# Print given number in reverse order

Tags: shell-script

```
clear
echo "Enter a number"
read n
sd=0
rev=0

while [ $n -gt 0 ]
do
    sd=$(( $n % 10 ))
    rev=$(( $rev *\ 10 + $sd ))
    n=$(( $n / 10 ))
done

echo "Reverse number of entered digit is $rev"
```

From the above code I am unable to get the required output. Instead, this error is displayed.

```
./Display: line 17: 0 *\ 10 + 4 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\ 10 + 4 ")
Reverse number of entered digit is 0
```

I don't know why this error is displayed, please help me to figure it out.

Comment: *\ is not a valid arithmetic operator in bash. What is your expected input and output?

Answer (score 18):

Numbers are text too. Text can be reversed with [rev](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rev) without any arythmetic.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
read -p "Enter a number: " num
echo $num | rev
```

Answer (score 3):

The error had already pointed out the problem clearly: `0 *\ 10 + 4` isn't a valid arithmetic expression.

I believe `*\` is a typo for `*`. Fix this typo and the script will be OK.

Comment: `\*` is advised notation for arithmetic multiplication as shell is performing expansion within the `(( ))` wchich may lead to `*` being interpreted as a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

`*\` is not the valid expression. Instead, try `*` which removes the special meaning of the character `*`. The character `*` is a wildcard character, which is why the error appeared.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Enter a number"
read n
sd=0
rev=0

while [ $n -gt 0 ]
do
    sd=$(( $n % 10 ))
    rev=`expr $rev \* 10 + $sd` 
    n=$(( $n / 10 ))
done

echo "Reverse number of entered digit is $rev"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It would be great if you could find the time to [edit your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/233698/edit) to explain how this works, so that others can benefit in the future. (You're more likely to get +1 votes if you do.)

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a wildcard character. Hence make sure that you add a '`\`' before using it

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Enter a number"
read n
sd=0
rev=0

while [ $n -gt 0 ]
do
    sd=$(( $n % 10 ))
    rev=$(( $rev * 10 + $sd ))
    n=$(( $n / 10 ))
done

echo "Reverse number of entered digit is $rev"
```

This should work *\ is not the correct form just use * for this

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "enter the number"
read n
rev=0
sd=0
while [$n -gt 0]
do
    sd=`expr $n%10`
    rev=`expr $rev\*10+$sd`
    n=`expr $n/10`
done
echo "the reverse number s: $rev"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  Did you try this?  Did it work?  If so, please describe your system, because this ***won't work*** on any normal system.  While you seem to be somewhat on the path to ***a*** solution (script) that does what the OP was trying to do, it's a bad way to do it.  And even if it did work, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in $*; do
  x=$i"  "$x
done;
echo "The Reverse order is $x"
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, on most patched versions of Bash, `$x` can no longer be set as a variable.  This is also a horrible answer.  Really bad answer.  Opposite of good.  Just bad.